# How can I remove the extra space around the toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

After making little changes to the example app of [this](https://github.com/michael-rapp/ChromeLikeTabSwitcher) library to support scrollable toolbar, some space lefts out around it and I can't figure out why.

[image]

Layout file for this tab (tab_text_view.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null">

    <de.mrapp.android.util.view.UnfocusableToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:theme="?attr/toolbarTheme"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/file_title"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/file_title"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

    </de.mrapp.android.util.view.UnfocusableToolbar>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="@dimen/tab_padding"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I only added navigation icon in the `MainActivity` and it's click listener. Can this be a problem of insets?

Comment: Try after removing `AppBarLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is space to the left of the text in the toolbar, it can be removed by removing this line in the first `TextView`:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
```

If this is not what you had in mind, a screenshot may help so I can better understand where the unwanted space is.

Comment: Please check the question again, I've attached a screenshot. Look around the toolbar, there is some space in all the directions.

Comment: @BrijeshShah Have you tried changing the `tabSwitcherToolbarPopupTheme` attribute in case it is causing this?

Comment: I can try. What changes should I make?

Answer (score 0):

Use `contentInsetLeft` and `contentInsetStart` in toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

     <de.mrapp.android.util.view.UnfocusableToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

Comment: you can try same property in `AppBarLayout` if not work add your `UnfocusableToolbar` code

Comment: Tried there as well, still negative.

Comment: `de.mrapp.android.util.view.UnfocusableToolbar` is your custom class or it's from any Library?

Comment: It's from library.

Comment: This does solves the issue. But, the toolbar is now of blue color whereas `@null` sets it to no color. Any workaround for that?

Comment: can you share screenshot,you can just remove the 'background' property from `AppBarLayout`

Comment: Will try that shortly and get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166861/discussion-between-brijesh-shah-and-jzm).

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your toolbar

```
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

if not work test it in normal toolbar if worked it mean problem  come from library